# super simple mistake, batch if statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

My short batch file keeps failing. what is wrong with my if?

```
:user
set /p usercommand = "Input: "

if %usercommand% equ "done"
echo got here!
goto end

else
echo not done
goto user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - with `set /p usercommand =` you set variable named `usercommand<space>`. Remove space after intended name (so it becames `set /p usercommand=`).

That said, this you will run you into another error as your *if else* syntax is incorrect. It must be:

```
if "%usercommand%" equ "done" (
 your commands here
) else (
 your commands here 
)
```

Please note I quoted `%usercommand%`. Without that your comparison will never be true (unless of course you require your input to be explicitly quoted)